# Create internal table as subset of columns of another internal table

Tags: abap

How do I get a single column of a table by index in ABAP?

For example I have:

```
A B C
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

and I want to get column B with [2,2].

EDIT:
This is my code

```
DATA:
 l_r_data            TYPE REF TO data,
 ld_e_cell_data         TYPE rrws_t_cell.

            CALL FUNCTION 'RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA'
              EXPORTING
*               i_infoprovider          =                  
                i_query                 = l_query_name           
*               i_view_id               =                  
                i_t_parameter           = l_t_parameter                 
              IMPORTING
                e_axis_info             = ld_e_axis_info           
                e_cell_data             = ld_e_cell_data                
                e_axis_data             = ld_e_axis_data                 
                e_txt_symbols           = ld_e_txt_symbols              
              EXCEPTIONS
                no_applicable_data      = 1                
                invalid_variable_values = 2                
                no_authority            = 3                
                abort                   = 4                
                invalid_view            = 6                
                OTHERS                  = 7.
            IF sy-subrc <> 0.
**             MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
**               WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
            ENDIF.
```

Now I just need the data from the second column of ld_e_cell_data  in l_r_data.

Comment: In ABAP, you can't extract a "matrix subset" as **easily** as in some other languages. Either you create a second table with the column B statically or via RTTC at runtime, and you fill the new table by looping at the original table, or you just loop at each line of the original table and use the value from the column B. Can you clarify your requirement please?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example that contains the data structure / table in ABAP code? I guess using the `VALUE ` operator might work.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? For what do you need to "get" it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"     Table lt_values contains the entries of column value.

```
   METHOD SEL_B.
        DATA: lt_values             TYPE standard table of rrxfloat  ,
              ld_e_cell_data         TYPE rrws_t_cell.
        FIELD-SYMBOLS: <cell> TYPE rrws_s_cell,
                       <val> TYPE rrxfloat.

        loop at ld_e_cell_data ASSIGNING <cell>.
            APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_values ASSIGNING <val>.
            <val> = <cell>-value.
        ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have an internal table `lt_itab1` with line structure `field1`, `field2`, ... and a second table `lt_itab2` with line structure only containing `field2`. You then can use:

```
lt_table_2 = CORRESPONDING #( lt_table_1 ).
```

Answer (score 0):

"SAP Netweaver Version below 7.4

```
REPORT zab_demo.

TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_connection,
    connid TYPE s_conn_id,
  END OF ty_connection.

DATA:
  flight                   TYPE sflight,
  flights                  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF sflight,
  connection_structured    TYPE ty_connection,
  connections_structured   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_connection,
  connections_unstructured TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF s_conn_id.

SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE flights UP TO 10 ROWS.

LOOP AT flights INTO flight.
  connection_structured-connid = flight-connid.
  APPEND connection_structured TO connections_structured.
ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT flights INTO flight.
  APPEND flight-connid TO connections_unstructured.
ENDLOOP.
```

"SAP Netweaver Version above 7.4 with inline data declarations

```
REPORT zab_demo2.

"Types can be of course from Data Dictionary, here we define types for demonstaration purpose only.
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_connection,
    connid TYPE s_conn_id,
  END OF ty_connection.

TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_cat,
    cat TYPE s_conn_id,
  END OF ty_cat.

TYPES ty_connections TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_connection WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY connid.

DATA:
  connections_structured2  TYPE ty_connections,
  connections_unstructured TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF s_conn_id,
  cats_structured          TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_cat WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY cat.

SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE @DATA(flights) UP TO 10 ROWS.

DATA(connections_structured) = CORRESPONDING ty_connections( flights ).

connections_structured2 = CORRESPONDING #( flights ).

"FOR can be combined with REDUCE, WHERE, FILTER and INIT, to get out more from BI Queries
DATA(connections_structured3) = VALUE ty_connections( FOR flight IN flights ( connid = flight-connid  ) ).
"Of course you can cut out 2 of 3 columns also, here we cut only one out
connections_unstructured = VALUE #( FOR flight IN flights ( flight-connid  ) ).

"Move column to other internal table with different field name
cats_structured = CORRESPONDING #( flights MAPPING cat = connid ).

"Move column to other internal table with different type
connections_unstructured = VALUE string_table( FOR flight IN flights ( CONV string( flight-connid ) ) ).
```